# Unable to set a View to the Dialog

Tags: java, android, eclipse, dialog, android-alertdialog

Please have a look at the following code

The code used to create the Custom Dialog. This class is an action class for an `AlertDialog`. When the user clicks on "Yes" button on that `AlertDialog`, this class get fired.
    private class PositiveDialogBtnAction implements DialogInterface.OnClickListener
        {

```
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), databaseConnector.getStreetAddress(selectedBranch), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            Dialog dialog = new Dialog(getApplicationContext());
            dialog.setContentView(R.layout.activity_call_dialog);
            dialog.setTitle("Select a Phone Number");

            dialog.show();
        }

    }
```

**activity_call_dialog.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".CallDialog" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**CallDialog.java**

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;

public class CallDialog extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_call_dialog);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_call_dialog, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

When I try to run the Custom Dialog, I get the following error

```
02-15 11:04:02.170: E/AndroidRuntime(585): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-15 11:04:02.170: E/AndroidRuntime(585): android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not for an application
02-15 11:04:02.170: E/AndroidRuntime(585):  at android.view.ViewRoot.setView(ViewRoot.java:531)
02-15 11:04:02.170: E/AndroidRuntime(585):  at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:177)
02-15 11:04:02.170: E/AndroidRuntime(585):  at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:91)
02-15 11:04:02.170: E/AndroidRuntime(585):  at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:241)
02-15 11:04:02.170: E/AndroidRuntime(585):  at com.example.esoftcallmanager.Form$PositiveDialogBtnAction.onClick(Form.java:155)
02-15 11:04:02.170: E/AndroidRuntime(585):  at com.android.internal.app.AlertController$ButtonHandler.handleMessage(AlertController.java:159)
02-15 11:04:02.170: E/AndroidRuntime(585):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-15 11:04:02.170: E/AndroidRuntime(585):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
02-15 11:04:02.170: E/AndroidRuntime(585):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
02-15 11:04:02.170: E/AndroidRuntime(585):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-15 11:04:02.170: E/AndroidRuntime(585):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
02-15 11:04:02.170: E/AndroidRuntime(585):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
02-15 11:04:02.170: E/AndroidRuntime(585):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
02-15 11:04:02.170: E/AndroidRuntime(585):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-15 11:04:05.520: I/Process(585): Sending signal. PID: 585 SIG: 9
```

Why is this? Please help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use

```
Dialog dialog = new Dialog(CallDialog.this);
```

instead of

```
Dialog dialog = new Dialog(getApplicationContext());
```

because for showing Dialog you will need to pass Activity Context instead of Application

Comment: Hi, I did it, but now it is saying "no enclosing of the type CallDialog is accessible in the scope" !!

Comment: @Yohan : if you are create Dialog in separate class then u will need to pass Activity Context using class constructor

Comment: After the edit I get the error "no enclosing of the type CallDialog is accessible in the scope"

Comment: @Yohan : post full class code in which u are using  Dialog dialog = new Dialog(CallDialog.this); code

Comment: Hi, Thank you for the reply :). Yes, I managed to do it by creating the Context separately, as a global variable :)